# Wordpress how to query multiple custom post types

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using `custom post types UI` plugin on my website.

Now I have blog posts ( default wp posts - news ) and a new custom post type ( articles ).

I want to show all the posts for these two post types on another page.
**but I can not combine this two together!**

Here is what i'm using to show articles posts:

```
public function News() {
  $terms = get_terms(['post_type' => 'articles','taxonomy' => "article_category",'hide_empty' => false,]);
```

Comment: And what is the exact issue ? I'm not very familiar with wordpress internals but I assume that there might be three ways:
1. Union is some SQL query
2. Have two datasets, map fields and join these collection in single one directly in php.
3. Just loop twice - 1st through articles, 2nd through posts ... with the same css/html

Comment: @iRoham Did my answer work? Please provide feedbacks. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

This could easily be done by using `wp_query`. Please **avoid** writing your own sql queries as much as possible because these `custom sql queries` would potentially make you vulnerable to `slq attacks`. You could combine your post types like this `'post_type' => array( 'post', 'articles' )`.

```php
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => array( 'post', 'articles' ),
  'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($custom_query) {
  while ($custom_query->have_posts()) {
    $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
    </a>
<?php
  }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi if WP Query does not work for you, you can try and get the id's of these two types. Then make a function that pulls the information that you need from each one based on their id's.

```
global $wpdb;

$ids = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT `ID` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` LIKE 'post' OR `post_type` LIKE 'articles'  ";

foreach($ids as $id){
//use another custom function to get the ACF or postmeta whatever it is you need
}
```